# videoInput device disconnection on waking up other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, video-capture

I'm using videoInput library for an application that tracks position of a device using multiple cameras. Using it, I got as far as perfectly extracting points from input image, but it stopped working once I moved the code to multiple thread.

Whenever the main thread is woken up by a video-capturing thread via conditional variable, the member object of object which is running the video-capturing thread seems to get deconstructed, even though the reference isn't lost in the process of waking up the other thread.

The main thread creates the capture threads and handles frames passed via vector. This is the initialization that happens in the main thread:

```
videoInput::setComMultiThreaded(true);
videoInput::listDevices(true);
```

In the capture thread, the following code is performed on member object `videoInput cap`

```
cap.setupDevice(deviceId, width, height);
cap.setAutoReconnectOnFreeze(deviceId, true, 1);
```

And then the following code is executed in a loop.

```
unsigned char* frame = new unsigned char[width * height * 3]();
cap.isFrameNew(capId);
cap.getPixels(capId, frame, false, true);
```

It works just as intended, but as soon as the data are passed to the main thread, the main thread is notified of the data and woken up with conditional variable, the device is disconnected (something that happens only in the videoInput object deconstructor), resulting in exception on the next iteration of the loop. I got the latest source compiled into a x64 static library.

I absolutely need the application to be multithreaded. Is there something important I am missing to make this work, or did I just hit some limitation of this library and need to use something else/make my own DirectShow wrapper?

I already tried OpenCV before and it just doesn't do the job for me (numberous issues, too much to name and too many stupid workarounds). I don't need this app to be cross-platform, I'm only targetting Windows 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing `videoInput cap` to a pointer and assigning it the videoInput object in constructor.